# ABP does not automatically use custom mapper class

Tags: automapper, mapper, abp

I have created a custom mapper class as below but ABP does not automatically register and use it while mapping.

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/4.4/Object-To-Object-Mapping#iobjectmapper-tsource-tdestination-interface

Sorry for less detail, i have added some below,

I have found that mycustommapperclass's interface different from my object mapper,

should I implement for all container types?

```
public class HierachyItemCustomMapper : IObjectMapper<HierachyItem, HierachyItemDto>, ITransientDependency
{
```

and my usage like

```
 var nodeListDto = ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<HierachyItem>, IEnumerable<HierachyItemDto>>(nodeList);
```

How can i handle this?

Obviously I am looking for a result instead of foreach iterator loop.

Edit:
it have found that it is known issue as below

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/94

Comment: Can you share your custom mapper class, so we can help you better?

Comment: Sorry , i have added some additional stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried just before and it seems it works as expected.

This is my `HierachyItemCustomMapper` class which I've created in the `Application` layer. (It should be created in the `Application` layer.)

```cs
public class HierachyItemCustomMapper : IObjectMapper<HierachyItem, HierachyItemDto>, ITransientDependency
{
   public HierachyItemDto Map(HierachyItem source)
   {
      return new HierachyItemDto
      {
         Name = source.Name
      };
   }

   public HierachyItemDto Map(HierachyItem source, HierachyItemDto destination)
   {
      destination.Name = source.Name;
            
      return destination;
   }
}
```

> I've just added a property named `Name` in my both classes (HierachyItem and HierachyItemDto) to test.

You probably didn't define it in the `Application` layer and that cause the problem. Can you check it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had defined it in Application and like you have said ObjectMapper.Map<HierachyItem, HierachyItemDto>(item);  works exactly as expected but ObjectMapper.Map<List<HierachyItem>, List<HierachyItemDto>>(nodeList); or ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<HierachyItem>, IEnumerable<HierachyItemDto>>(nodeList); does not. Did you try in a container as those?

Comment: Yes, @Kutt you're right. When I used it with IEnumerable<> or List<> it is not mapped.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple , your defination is wrong
it should be like that

```
public class HierachyItemCustomMapper : IObjectMapper<IEnumerable<HierachyItem>,
IEnumerable<HierachyItemDto>>, ITransientDependency {}
```

as it searches for exact defination match , and if you want to add also capability of using `ObjectMapper.Map<HierachyItem, HierachyItemDto>`
you can make your custom mapper defination like that

```
public class HierachyItemCustomMapper : IObjectMapper<IEnumerable<HierachyItem>,
IEnumerable<HierachyItemDto>>,  IObjectMapper<HierachyItem, HierachyItemDto> , 
ITransientDependency {}
```

and you will implement both
good luck